# BigQuery python client Table not found error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a script where I am trying to create a table fresh each time the script is run

```
# Delete the temp table if it exists
query = f'''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org1.scratch.temp_table'''
result = client.query(query)
result.result()
if result.errors:
    raise Exception('Table was not successfullly dropped in bigQuery: ', result.errors)

# Create the temp table
query = f'''CREATE TABLE org1.scratch.temp_table LIKE org1.scratch.data_all'''
result = client.query(query)
result.result()
if result.errors:
    raise Exception('Table was not successfullly created in bigQuery: ', result.errors)
print('Create table temp_table', result)

# Insert the ship info values into the temp table
result = client.insert_rows_json('org1.scratch.temp_table', all_info)
```

But I am getting an error when trying to insert rows:

```
Create table scratch.data_all <google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator object
at 0x000001DBF3176CB0>
Create table temp_table <google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator object at 0x000001DBF31764A0>

google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/org/datasets/scratch/tables/temp_table/insertAll?prettyPrint=false: Table 672634735366:scratch.temp_table not found
```

From what I understand, calling the result() method should wait for the query to finish, so it should be deleted and then created in the correct sequence. I'm also not seeing an error when printing the result for either of the first two queries, although I'm not sure if the empty row iterator means it was successful.

Comment: Needed to check the result.errors to find the issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340161/check-if-bigquery-query-was-successful-or-not-in-python)

Comment: Scratch that, even with no errors from above code, I am still often getting the issue

Comment: Turns out the temp_table is successfully created, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the 404 error on the insert

Answer (score 0):

Per this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013949/bigquery-404-table-is-truncated-when-insert-right-after-truncate), if you are sure that the table exists and you are still getting this error message, it could be because of a delay in metadata consistency. In this case, you can try backing off and retrying the operation.